# Remove the [label] tag

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup-request

[label](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/label) is an undefined meta-tag that is used in many ways and does not appear to add value:

- naming of system-related objects (partitions, files, ports, devices)
- identifying names for rows/columns, chart elements, document components, etc.
- categories in applications like email
- printing labels
- music publisher

Differentiating the naming function isn't a useful sub-category for the existing application-specific tags (e.g., [chart](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/chart) is adequate; a special tag for the chart labels isn't necessary).  I would add one specific label.  [label-printer](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/label-printer) is an existing tag but there is not a [label-printing](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/label-printing) tag.  Printing labels has a special set of requirements and problems, so a dedicated tag would be useful.

Comment: Is it worth differentiating between [tag:label-printer] and [tag:label-printing]? I would think that the latter could not happen without the former...

Comment: And that would be incorrect thinking.  A label printer is a dedicated, label printing device.  The term applies to what is almost universally a specialize printer that prints labels one at a time from roll stock that is fairly narrow.  They have certain issues unique to them, like drivers, outputting from something other than dedicated software, etc.  Label printing is a process that can also be performed by regular printers, so there is issue overlap.  Printing labels with a regular printer has unique formatting issues, among other things.  One tag focuses on hardware, the other on a process.

Comment: I just don't see what the problem is, if label-printing can happen with your everyday printer, wouldn't questions regarding printing labels be better tagged with a) the program requesting the print operation, and b) the name/product tag of the printer in question? For example: "*How can I set Microsoft Word to print labels?` [microsoft-word][brother-printer]*"

Comment: Obviously specialised [label-printer]s are different, but I don't see why we need to differentiate label printing from other forms of printing.

Comment: Printing labels in a regular printer is not printer specific.  It could be application specific.  The task has characteristics different from most normal printing tasks--specialized formatting, sometimes generating output in a special sequence/arrangement or incorporating merged elements, sometimes dealing with media issues.  If the output is to a label printer, there are additional specialized issues.  Users would think to use [label-printer] for device issues and [label-printing] for process issues.

Comment: `[label-printing]` would be sufficient. A `[label-printer]` is just another `[printer]`; not different enough to earn itself its own tag.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg - I suppose that could work.  There is already a [label-printer] tag.  What level rep is needed to rename that to [label-printing]?  Would that require a tag renaming question?