# Request to rename [label-printer] tag

Tags: discussion, retag-request

Previous question [remove-the-label-tag](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/8812/remove-the-label-tag) discusses cleaning up the [label](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/label) tag.  One aspect of that is pulling out questions that deal with label printing and putting them under a specific tag.  There was discussion in the comments about the existing [label-printer](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/label-printer) tag (hardware issues) vs. a new [label-printing](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/label-printing) tag (process issues).  Oliver Salzburg's recommandation was to put both under the more generic term [label-printing], which appears to have general agreement.

Since [label-printer](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/label-printer) already exists (19 questions), the most efficient way to do this would be to rename the tag to [label-printing](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/label-printing) and then move the additional questions to that tag.  This is a request for someone with adequate rep to rename that tag.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg - I thought retagging referred to changing the tags on the questions, not renaming a tag (which I assume would automatically be reflected on the questions).  Can tags not be renamed; the process requires creating a new tag and then changing the question tags?

Comment: Tags can be renamed through the merge operation. I only *retagged* this question because the cleanups are usually meant for tag removal (but they can also include retagging).